# Separate bean for any action or one bean for all?

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a jsf page that perform three actions. Is it better, in term of design, to have one separate bean for any action or a single bean with all actions?

Comment: Single bean class is enough to get better design for any number of actions. It will reduce memory size of project. For each & every "@managedBean " annotation it takes memory. So., single bean class for all action property is best way. When you go with real time web application., this & all main factor.

Comment: Keep with single bean + view scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the functional requirements, but generally you use one request/view scoped bean per `<h:form>`.

So, if all actions are in such way related to each other that they really belong in the same form, then just put them in the same bean. If those actions are however completely unrelated to each other (e.g. login form, contact form, language selection form), and thus sit each in its own `<h:form>`, then they should each refer their own bean.

Answer (score 0):

**In term of design:** It is better to have one Bean with the view. As JSF is MVC,

**In term of performance:** better performance will be achieved by linking each view with one bean, but in case your view has heavy actions (like 2 tables "master detail"), so it is better to have bean for each action.